# How to allow only comma for decimal?

Tags: c#, wpf, events, key

I need to restrict all symbols, except space, 0-9 in numeric keyboard, 0-9 in numpad and comma. I handled everything but comma in numpad:

```
e.Handled = !((e.Key >= Key.D0 && e.Key <= Key.D9) || 
        (e.Key >= Key.NumPad0 && e.Key <= Key.NumPad9) ||
        e.Key == Key.Space || e.Key == Key.OemComma);
```

The problem with comma in numpad is recognized as `Decimal`, but `Decimal` is also a dot, which I should forbid.

How can I separate `Decimal` by dot and comma?

Comment: You keyboard really have a comma in the numpad?

Comment: Yes. It depends on keyboard layout. For English layout Decimal is dot, for Russian layout Decimal is comma. I need to handle it.

Comment: @Ecnerwal the key right to '0'. `.` or `,` depending on localization

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Key.Decimal`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa250037(v=vs.60).aspx). It is a key on the numpad that corresponds to `.` on the US layout, and `,` on the Russian layout.

```
e.Handled = !((e.Key >= Key.D0 && e.Key <= Key.D9) || 
            (e.Key >= Key.NumPad0 && e.Key <= Key.NumPad9) ||
            e.Key == Key.Space || e.Key == Key.Decimal);
```

Comment: And that's a problem: I need to allow only comma in Decimal

Comment: @Batmannn Did you test it? It only allow comma in `Decimal` while you are using *Russian layout*. It just allow `.` only when you are using another layout like US layout. So what is the problem this is exactly what is expected.

Comment: I tested it. When I use English layout - it allows dots, when I use Russian layout - it allows commas (dots and commas are decimal). But I need to forbid dots as decimals while I have English layout.

Comment: I need something like this:
if (Decimal is comma) - allow
if (Decimal is dot) - forbid

Comment: @Batmannn This is impossible because culture decimal separator is used by default depending on localization!

Comment: Uh oh, that's a problem :C

Answer (score 0):

According to the comments in another answer, it sounds like what you are asking for is how to determine `if (decimal is comma)`. If that's the case, then this should help:

```
var decimalSeparator = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture
    .NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator.ToString();

e.Handled = !((e.Key >= Key.D0 && e.Key <= Key.D9) || 
              (e.Key >= Key.NumPad0 && e.Key <= Key.NumPad9) ||
              (e.Key == Key.Space) || 
              (e.Key == Key.Decimal && decimalSeparator == ","));
```